# Roblox tool giver script meant for one player but keeps giving

Tags: roblox

I wrote a script which gives a player a tool (from Replicated Storage) when they touch a brick. The intention is that no other player can get a tool once the brick is touched the first time. My code doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

```
TeleportToolActivated = false


TeleportPad.Touched:Connect(function(other)
    if TeleportToolActivated == false then

    -- Check if the other part is part of a player
    if other.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil then
            TeleportToolActivated = true
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(other.Parent)

        -- If there is a tool with the same name in the backpack already, then return
        if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild(TeleportTool.Name) then return end
        
        local tool = TeleportTool:Clone()
            tool.Parent = player.Backpack
            TeleportToolActivated = true

        end
    
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a local script?
make sure it is just a local script else it would give the tool to all other players as well

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question? Can you make your Answer more assertive?